# avoid calling a function in angularjs on ng-switch / ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function called `isShiftActive(shift)` which is called to build divisions on my page based on its `boolean` value. The total number of divsions to be built are around `31*51=1581`.

The controller calls the function `isShiftActive` **790 odd times** during page load which is alright, but after page load, for any action on the page the `isShiftActive` function is called **790** times every time which makes the page way too slow.

Kindly suggest an alternative, i am using `ng-switch=isShiftActive(shift)`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to evaluate watch expressions only once you can use [bindonce](https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce). It evaluates the watch once and removed the watch immediately after.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i am not using watch expressions here, it is simply a controller function which is being repeatedly called

Comment: a function call is also an expression. everything in {{ }} is an expression being evaluated during digest. bindonce just removed the watch once an initial value has been calculated. If the values are not suppose to change after the initial value has been set - bindonce is the solution. If you'r using latest (unstable) version of angular (>1.3 i think) you have that build in.